# Options for deploying a Windows applications with SQL Server database on my client machines (local DB)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, deployment, windows

I'm working on a VB.NET application that works with SQL Server database. I created my database through SQL Server 2008 Express. The SQL Server DB would be **local, thus installed on client's machine itself**. Of course I won't buy an instance for each one of my clients for a local offline database.
In my region, I can see all shops bought their software for like less than $1000 and they got SQL Server installed (**not the Express edition**). How are they doing that, given that each license would cost more than $10000?

Should I buy one license and create my database on it, then copying the database and install the Express edition on my clients' computers and this way I can benefit from some additional features?

N.B. the user would interact with the database through the app, thus no GUI for SQL Server would be needed at all.

Comment: you can have only one db server like Network Service, no local. So every client can access to the seem db server.

Comment: i need every client to have his own DB on his own omputer

Comment: internet connection in my country is rubbish. besides, most of my clients won't have internet.